# How to detect whether the client machine has installed silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

i am using silverlight 5 and hosted the SL5 application.

As we all have seen, when we come in the homepage of this website, we will see a message telling us to install silverlight if we haven't installed silverlight. How to detect if the client machine has not installed silverlight ?
 if not installed i need to show a custom message and take the user into micorsoft site in order to download the silverlight instead of the install silverlight message.

i have verified the below URL and did the same thing..

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Si...ction.aspx

but i hosted my application and i did the same in the above url but it does not worked..
i got the default result only but not my customized information's if the client doesn't have silverlight.

i am using silverlight 5.

Regards

gopal.s

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838126(v=vs.95).aspx

The Silverlight.js file does all the magic. In fact you if you create a new silver light project in Visual Studio 2010 detection of Silverlight and automatic install is all handled for you.

[Silverlight Install and Upgrade Experience](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/pre-loaders-and-installers/silverlight-install-and-upgrade-experience) has all the information on customizing the install experience